# Syntax error when defining type aliases

Tags: c++, c++11

When trying to define the simplest type alias I get the following error:
`syntax error : missing ';' before '='` on the 4th line.
The code is quite simple:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//data type aliases - using
using C = char;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This does not happen if I use the typedef approach. What is the proper way/place to define the type alias by utilizing the `using` keyword and why this error occurs? I am using the VS 2010 C++ compiler.

Comment: Are you sure your compiler version supports type aliases?

Comment: I am using the VS 2010 C++ compiler. I have updated the question to include that information.

Comment: Type aliases [aren't supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) in VS2010 AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to define a type alias. VS 2010 does not support this feature so you'll need to upgrade in order to use it.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Nice one Tartan.